# Issue in filtering on Hive Map column with combination of key values(AND Condition) in Spark sql

Tags: dictionary, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a hive table with Map columntype `key` which stores values in key value pairs.
I need to write filter condition combining both the key values

Example dataset:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| column_value  | metric_name  |         key          |
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| A37B          | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"1"}  |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"2"}  |
| ANB_200       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"3"}  |
| ANB_201       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"4"}  |
| AS82_RE       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR001       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"2"}  |
| ATTR001_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR002       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR002_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR003       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR004       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR005       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | {0:"202009",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | {0:"202009",1:"5"}  |
```

I need to write a spark sql query to filter based on `Key` column with NOT IN condition with commination of both keys.

```
select * from table where key[0] between 202006 and 202009 and key NOT IN (0:"202009",1:"5)
```

Expected output:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| column_value  | metric_name  |         key          |
+---------------+--------------+----------------------+
| A37B          | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"1"}  |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"2"}  |
| ANB_200       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"3"}  |
| ANB_201       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"4"}  |
| AS82_RE       | Mean         | {0:"202006",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR001       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"2"}  |
| ATTR001_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR002       | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR002_RE    | Mean         | {0:"202007",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR003       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"3"}  |
| ATTR004       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"4"}  |
| ATTR005       | Mean         | {0:"202008",1:"5"}  |
| ATTR006       | Mean         | {0:"202009",1:"4"}  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map() function to convert NOT IN parameter to map:

```
select * from your_data 
 where key[0] between  202006 and 202009 
   and key NOT IN ( map(0,"202009",1,"5") ); --can be many map() comma separated
```

Comment: This query is working fine in HiveQL. But when i try this query in Spark SQL, it is not working. Need help!

Comment: @Arvinth  If it is MAP function, then try this `WHERE NOT(key[0]=202009 and key[1]=5)` instead of `key NOT IN ( map(0,"202009",1,"5") )`

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

Using **Spark Scala**

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------------+-----------+------------------+
|column_value|metric_name|key               |
+------------+-----------+------------------+
|A37B        |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"1"}|
|ACCOUNT_ID  |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"2"}|
|ANB_200     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"3"}|
|ANB_201     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"4"}|
|AS82_RE     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"5"}|
|ATTR001     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"2"}|
|ATTR001_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"3"}|
|ATTR002     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"4"}|
|ATTR002_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"5"}|
|ATTR003     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"3"}|
|ATTR004     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"4"}|
|ATTR005     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"5"}|
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"4"}|
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"5"}|
+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Create schema to match `key` column value.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala>  val schema = DataType
.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"0","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"1","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""")
.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

Printing schema of `key` column.

```
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
```

Applying **schema** json to **key** column in DataFrame.

```
scala> :paste
// Convert key column values to valid json & then apply schema json.
df
.withColumn("key_new",
    from_json(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                $"key",
                "0:",
                "\"0\":"
            ),
            "1:",
            "\"1\":"
        ),
        schema
    )
)
.filter(
    $"key_new.0".between(202006,202009) &&
    !($"key_new.0" === 202009 && $"key_new.1" === 5)
).show(false)
```

**Final Output**

```
+------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|column_value|metric_name|key               |key_new    |
+------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|A37B        |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"1"}|[202006, 1]|
|ACCOUNT_ID  |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"2"}|[202006, 2]|
|ANB_200     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"3"}|[202006, 3]|
|ANB_201     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"4"}|[202006, 4]|
|AS82_RE     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"5"}|[202006, 5]|
|ATTR001     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"2"}|[202007, 2]|
|ATTR001_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"3"}|[202007, 3]|
|ATTR002     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"4"}|[202007, 4]|
|ATTR002_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"5"}|[202007, 5]|
|ATTR003     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"3"}|[202008, 3]|
|ATTR004     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"4"}|[202008, 4]|
|ATTR005     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"5"}|[202008, 5]|
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"4"}|[202009, 4]|
+------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

Using **Spark SQL**

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from data").show(false)
+------------+-----------+------------------+
|column_value|metric_name|key               |
+------------+-----------+------------------+
|A37B        |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"1"}|
|ACCOUNT_ID  |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"2"}|
|ANB_200     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"3"}|
|ANB_201     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"4"}|
|AS82_RE     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"5"}|
|ATTR001     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"2"}|
|ATTR001_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"3"}|
|ATTR002     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"4"}|
|ATTR002_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"5"}|
|ATTR003     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"3"}|
|ATTR004     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"4"}|
|ATTR005     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"5"}|
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"4"}|
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"5"}|
+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.sql("""
WITH table_data AS (
    SELECT
        column_value,
        metric_name,
        key,
        get_json_object(replace(replace(key,'0:','\"0\":'),'1:','\"1\":'),'$.0') as k,
        get_json_object(replace(replace(key,'0:','\"0\":'),'1:','\"1\":'),'$.1') as v
    FROM data
)
SELECT
    column_value,
    metric_name,
    key,
    k,
    v
FROM table_data
WHERE
    (k between 202006 and 202009) AND
    !(k = 202009 AND V = 5)
""").show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+------------+-----------+------------------+------+---+
|column_value|metric_name|key               |k     |v  |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------+---+
|A37B        |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"1"}|202006|1  |
|ACCOUNT_ID  |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"2"}|202006|2  |
|ANB_200     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"3"}|202006|3  |
|ANB_201     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"4"}|202006|4  |
|AS82_RE     |Mean       |{0:"202006",1:"5"}|202006|5  |
|ATTR001     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"2"}|202007|2  |
|ATTR001_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"3"}|202007|3  |
|ATTR002     |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"4"}|202007|4  |
|ATTR002_RE  |Mean       |{0:"202007",1:"5"}|202007|5  |
|ATTR003     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"3"}|202008|3  |
|ATTR004     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"4"}|202008|4  |
|ATTR005     |Mean       |{0:"202008",1:"5"}|202008|5  |
|ATTR006     |Mean       |{0:"202009",1:"4"}|202009|4  |
+------------+-----------+------------------+------+---+


scala>
```

Comment: Is it not possible to perform this filter in Spark SQL itself

Comment: what is data type of ```key``` column ??

Comment: Key column is `Map` datatype.